# Kusto/Dataexplorer JDBC Connector and Functions as Views

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Small question: Does someone know if it is possible to expose Kusto functions (Azure Data Explorer) as views via JDBC.
Background:

- We have some (3rd Party cannot change) tools that can connect to JDBC targets. Unfortunately, most of them are not able to see or use procedures/functions, but operate only on views and tables.
- We have some quite complicated queries implemented in KQL which we would like to use in those tools and cannot be easily done in SQL.

Kusto functions are exposed as procedures by the JDBC-Driver. Is there a way to specify that some functions are exported as views (which they are, semantically?). We have not found anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Kusto stored functions are indeed modelled in SQL metadata views and stored procedures as stored procedures or/and functions, aka routines (see sys.sp_stored_procedures, information_schema.routines).

Saying that, if KQL function doesn't have parameters, SQL query from it, like it was a view, would work, e.g.: select * from kusto.MyFunction

Comment: The functions are exported as stored procedures (visible in sys.sp_stored_procedures). The problem is that some of those tools do a metadata fetch and show us only tables (and real views, which kusto functions are not). Even if we can do a select * from kusto.function the tools still expect some metadata to work with, thus we can only work with the original tables and the limited SQL support of kusto (there are tools which generate SQL and thus we run also in trouble). We are looking for a way to hide the kusto query from those tools...